# Executing a method only once a day android java

Tags: java, android

```
public ListenableFuture<?> fakeUpload() {
    ImmutableList.Builder<Keys> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BYTES];
      RAND.nextBytes(bytes);
      builder.add(
          Keys.newBuilder()
              .setKeyBytes(bytes)
              .setIntervalNumber(FAKE_INTERVAL_NUM)
              .build());

    }

    return doUpload(builder.build(), true);
  }
```

I want to make these keys upload only once a day.
How can i do that?

Comment: save the last date of your upload somewhere, when the app launches, read that date, if they dont match, upload

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. Note that accepting and up-voting answers is the way to say _thanks_ on Stack Overflow (don't use comments for that). – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can write this code in application activity where you want to or create a service and write the code there :-

```
private fun shouldUploadFakeKeys(): Boolean {
    if (sharedPreferenceUtil.getInt(Constants.EXTRA_DAILY_KEYS_UPLOAD) != getTodaysDate()) {
        sharedPreferenceUtil.putBoolean(Contants.EXTRA_HAS_FAKE_KEYS_UPLOADED_TODAY,false)
        return true
    } else if (sharedPreferenceUtil.getBoolean(Contants.EXTRA_HAS_FAKE_KEYS_UPLOADED_TODAY)) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
fun getTodaysDate(): Int {
        return ZonedDateTime.now().dayOfMonth
    }
```

Create a constants file if you don't have one already:-

Constants.kt

```
class Constants{
    companionObject{
         const val EXTRA_DAILY_KEYS_UPLOAD = "EXTRA_DAILY_KEYS_UPLOAD"
         const val EXTRA_HAS_FAKE_KEYS_UPLOADED_TODAY = "EXTRA_HAS_FAKE_KEYS_UPLOADED_TODAY"
    }
}
```